# Mi TimePickerDialog y DatePickerDialog no modifican mi EditText cuando Edito la persona (Sqlite)

Tags: java, android

Tengo una `clase` que utilizo para añadir y editar personas en mi `ListView` mediante `Sqlite`, cuando añado una persona mi `editTextFecha` lo edito mediante `TimePickerDialog` y `DatePickerDialog` y funciona perfectamente, pero cuando edito la persona mi `editTextFecha` solo se actualiza si lo modifico manualmente (con el teclado), si utilizo `TimePickerDialog` y `DatePickerDialog` no manda nada al `EditTexFecha` ¿A qué puede deberse este error?

*Pongo un *GIF* del problema, como podéis ver cuando añado la persona se edita correctamente, pero cuando la edito, no

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así funciona perfectamente cuando añado una persona:

```
  final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
    dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    hora = calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minutos = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    mostrarFecha();
    selectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            dia = dayOfMonth;
            mes = month;
            ano = year;
            age.setDateOfBirth(ano, mes, dia);
            calculateAge();
            mostrarFecha();
            mostrarHora();
        }
    };

}

private void mostrarHora() {
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {
                    hora = hourOfDay;
                    minutos = minute;
                    mostrarFecha();

                }
            }, hora, minutos, true);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}

private void calculateAge() {
    age.calcualteYear();
    age.calcualteMonth();
    age.calcualteDay();
    String[] dayMonthYear = age.getResult().split(":");
    String year = dayMonthYear[2];
    editTextEdad.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.edad_actual)
+ " " + year + " " + (getResources().getString(R.string.age)));

}


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case 0:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, selectorFecha, ano, mes, dia);
    }
    return null;
}

public void mostrarCalendario(View control) {
    showDialog(TIPO_DIALOGO);
}


public void mostrarFecha() {
    editTextFecha.setText (dia + "/" + (mes + 1) 
+ "/" + ano + " " + hora + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutos));
}
```

Pero cuando edito la persona, solo puedo editar mi `editTextFecha` manualmente (con el teclado) y no con `TimePickerDialog` y `DatePickerDialog` porque no le envía nada

```
private void editarPersona() {
    baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(EditarPersonaActivity.this);

    try {
        int id = extras.getInt("id");
        Persona persona = new Persona(id, editTextFecha.getText()
                .toString());

        baseDatos.actualizarRegistros(id, persona.getFecha());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        baseDatos.cerrar();
    }
}
```

Método `actualizarRegistros` de `DatabaseHandler`

```
 public void actualizarRegistros(int id, String fecha){
        ContentValues actualizarDatos = new ContentValues();
        actualizarDatos.put("fecha", fecha);
        String where = "_id=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};
        try{
            this.getReadableDatabase().update("Personas", actualizarDatos, where, whereArgs);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            String error =  e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    }
```

Si hace falta que ponga la `clase` completa o algún otra información, avisar por favor.

Comment: Nadie sabe dónde tengo mi error?

Comment: ¿Revisaste lo que hace el método `actualizarRegistros` de tu clase `DatabaseHandler` ? Si no ves el error, edita tu pregunta y muestra lo que hace dicho método.

Comment: Acabo de añadir el método que me pides y un GIF para que podáis ver el error, también he editado de nuevo pregunta porque he podido avanzar en la solución, gracias @A.Cedano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT definitivo, espero

```
    public class EditarPersonaActivity extends Activity {
        // Objetos.
        private Button butonGuardar;
        private EditText editTextFecha;
        private DatabaseHandler baseDatos;
        private Bundle extras;
        private int dia, mes, ano, hora, minutos;
        private static final int TIPO_DIALOGO = 0;
        private static DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener selectorFecha;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.editar_persona);
            butonGuardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonGuardar);
            editTextFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFecha);

            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            hora = calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minutos = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            selectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    dia = dayOfMonth;
                    mes = month;
                    ano = year;
                    mostrarHora();
System.out.println("mostrarHora desde onDateSet");

                }
            };

        }

        private void mostrarHora() {
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {
                            hora = hourOfDay;
                            minutos = minute;
                            mostrarFecha();

System.out.println("mostrarFecha desde onTimeSet");


                        }
                    }, hora, minutos, true);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
                case 0:
                    return new DatePickerDialog(this, selectorFecha, ano, mes, dia);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void mostrarCalendario(View control) {
            showDialog(TIPO_DIALOGO);
        }

        public void mostrarFecha() {
System.out.println("Llamaste a mostrarFecha");

            editTextFecha.setText(dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano + " " + hora + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutos)
            );


            // Recupera en un Objeto Bundle si tiene valores que fueron pasados como
            // parametro de una actividad.

         extras = getIntent().getExtras();

//Lo sacaste del if pero no lo pusiste aquí:
                editarPersona();

         if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
                editTextFecha.setText(extras.getString("fecha"));


    //// lo saco como me comentas            editarPersona();


            }

            butonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (verificarCampoFecha()) {
                        if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
                            editarPersona();
                        } else {
                            insertarNuevoPersona();
                        }
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        if (editTextFecha.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private boolean verificarCampoFecha() {
            if (editTextFecha.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    ////////////////// Metodo privado que insertar una nueva Persona.

        private void insertarNuevoPersona() {
            baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(EditarPersonaActivity.this);

            try {
    ///////////////// Crear objeto de la persona
                Persona persona = new Persona(editTextFecha.getText().toString());
    ////////////////// se inserta una nueva persona
                baseDatos.insertarPersona(persona);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                baseDatos.cerrar();
            }
        }

    ///////////////////////////////// metodo privado para editar una persona existente

        private void editarPersona() {
System.out.println("Llamaste a mostrarFecha");
            baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(EditarPersonaActivity.this);

//Esto había que comentarlo
//            mostrarFecha();

            try {
    ///////////////// crear objeto persona
                int id = extras.getInt("id");
                Persona persona = new Persona(id, editTextFecha.getText()
                        .toString());

                baseDatos.actualizarRegistros(id, persona.getFecha());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                baseDatos.cerrar();
            }
        }

        public boolean estadoEditarPersona() {
            if (extras != null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

## Actualizado después de ver una visión más general del código

**Prueba a:**
Según he entendido, quieres que, **al seleccionar la hora, te actualice sin necesidad de pulsar en el botón**. ¿Es correcto? Viendo que, después de seleccionar la hora llamas al método `mostrarFechaEnvia()`, tendrías que actualizar la persona llamando el método que hace dicha acción. Entonces, llama al método `editarPersona()` desde el método `mostrarFechaEnvia()` de la clase `EditarPersonaActivity` :

```
public void mostrarFechaEnvia() {
    editTextFecha.setText(dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano + " " + hora + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutos));


    extras = getIntent().getExtras();


    if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
        editTextFecha.setText(extras.getString("fecha"));
//agregar
    editarPersona();

    }
```

## Actualizado

a. Actualizar el registro al elegir una hora en el TimePicker (es lo que necesitas según lo que has planteado):

```
private void mostrarHora() {
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {
                    hora = hourOfDay;
                    minutos = minute;

//Actualizas una vez has elegido la hora
         baseDatos.actualizarRegistros(id, persona.getFecha());

                    mostrarFecha();

                }
            }, hora, minutos, true);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
//    ... lo que sigue del código
```

b. Otra posibilidad, si aceptar fuese un botón y quieres que se actualice el registro sólo tienes que agregar un listener (si es que no existe) a dicho boton y llamar el método (no aplica en tu caso como has manifestado en un comentario, pero lo dejo por si es útil a alguien):

```
baseDatos.actualizarRegistros(id, persona.getFecha());
```

Ejemplo:

```
 final Button btnAceptar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnaceptar);
 btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         baseDatos.actualizarRegistros(id, persona.getFecha());
     }
 });
```

Por supuesto, tu clase DatabaseHandler debe estar instanciada desde donde llames el método `actualizarRegistros` y en este caso tu botón en el XML se llama `btnaceptar`.

Otra posibilidad sería llamar el método `actualizarRegistros` inmediatamente después de haber seleccionado una hora, en el listener `onTimeSet`, pero ello no te daría la posibilidad de estar seguro que es la hora que quieres y confirmarlo pulsando en aceptar.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53993/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-mi-timepickerdialog-y-datepickerdialog-no-modi).

Comment: Finalmente, lo he conseguido solucionar, como bien me dijiste era más problema de lógica que de código, tenía el método en un mal sitio, solamente he tenido que cambiarlo de lugar y añadir sus } correspondiente y ya actualiza sin problema con el mismo método, así que marco como solucionado! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @A.Cedano ahora tengo un problema que tiene algo que ver con esto, pásate si puedes: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50776/por-qu%C3%A9-no-muestra-la-fecha-hora-guardada-en-mi-sqlite-al-editarlo

Comment: Me alegro :) Un saludo.