# ¿Por qué no muestra la fecha/hora guardada en mi Sqlite al editarlo?

Tags: java, android

Tengo una `ListView` que voy rellenando con los datos que guardo en mi `Sqlite` tengo un campo que es `editTextFecha` que lo relleno con la fecha/hora que selecciono en mi `DatePickerDialog` y `TimePickerDialog`, creo una nueva persona seleccionando la fecha y hora que necesito y hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando edito esa persona, el campo (`editTextFecha`) me sale vacío, y no sé por qué, puedo editarlo perfectamente y me guarda bien la edición, pero ¿por qué no me muestra lo qué seleccione al crearla? El problema viene es que si entro en editar tengo que volver a seleccionar una fecha y hora sí o sí y no quiero, quiero que este la fecha que seleccioné anteriormente y si quiero cambiarla, pero no por obligación.

Dejo un *GIF* para que veáis el problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi clase `editarPersonaActivity` (en la que creo y edito la persona)

```
public class EditarPersonaActivity extends Activity {
    // Objetos.
    private Button butonGuardar;
    private EditText editTextFecha;
    private DatabaseHandler baseDatos;
    private Bundle extras;
    private int dia, mes, ano, hora, minutos;
    private static final int TIPO_DIALOGO = 0;
    private static DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener selectorFecha;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editar_persona);
        butonGuardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonGuardar);
        editTextFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFecha);

        final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        hora = calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minutos = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        selectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                dia = dayOfMonth;
                mes = month;
                ano = year;
// muestro "TimePickerDialog"
                mostrarHora();
            }
        };

    }

    private void mostrarHora() {
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {
                        hora = hourOfDay;
                        minutos = minute;


//// envio la fecha y hora a "editTextFecha"


                             mostrarFecha();
                    }
                }, hora, minutos, true);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, selectorFecha, ano, mes, dia);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void mostrarCalendario(View control) {
        showDialog(TIPO_DIALOGO);




        butonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (verificarCampoFecha()) {
                    if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
                        editarPersona();
                    } else {
                        insertarNuevoPersona();
                    }
                    finish();
                } else {
                    if (editTextFecha.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // verifico que los cambios están rellenos

    private boolean verificarCampoFecha() {
        if (editTextFecha.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

////////////////// Metodo privado que insertar una nueva Persona.

    private void insertarNuevoPersona() {
        baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(EditarPersonaActivity.this);

        try {
///////////////// Crear objeto de la persona
            Persona persona = new Persona(editTextFecha.getText().toString());
////////////////// se inserta una nueva persona
            baseDatos.insertarPersona(persona);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            baseDatos.cerrar();
        }
    }

    public void mostrarFecha() {
        editTextFecha.setText(dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano + " " + hora + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutos)
        );
    }


 //// aquí edito la persona

    private void editarPersona() {
        baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(EditarPersonaActivity.this);

// llamo al método para que se actualice cuando selecciono una fecha y hora nueva en Time/DateDialogPicker
        mostrarFecha();

        try {
///////////////// crear objeto persona
            int id = extras.getInt("id");
            Persona persona = new Persona(id, editTextFecha.getText()
                    .toString());

            baseDatos.actualizarRegistros(id, persona.getFecha());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            baseDatos.cerrar();
        }
    }

    public boolean estadoEditarPersona() {
        if (extras != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

`DatabaseHandler`

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static String RUTA_BASE_DATOS = "/data/data/nueva.pruebaedittext/databases/";
    private static String NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS = "basedb";
    private static final int VERSION_BASE_DATOS = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase base_datos;
    private Context contexto;
    private String SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS = "CREATE TABLE if not exists personas (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, " +
            "fecha TEXT, ruta_imagen TEXT)";
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS, null, VERSION_BASE_DATOS);
        this.contexto = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Personas");
        db.execSQL(SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS);
    }
    public void insertarPersona(Persona persona){
        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
        valores.put("fecha", persona.getFecha());
        this.getWritableDatabase().insert("Personas", null, valores);
    }
    public void actualizarRegistros(int id, String fecha){
        ContentValues actualizarDatos = new ContentValues();
        actualizarDatos.put("fecha", fecha);
        String where = "_id=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};
        try{
            this.getReadableDatabase().update("Personas", actualizarDatos, where, whereArgs);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            String error =  e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    }

    public Persona getPersona(int p_id) {
        String[] columnas = new String[]{"_id", "fecha"};
        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("Personas", columnas, "_id" + "= " + p_id, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        Persona persona = new Persona(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1));
        return persona;
    }

    public void cerrar(){
        this.close();
    }
    public Cursor obtenerTodasPersonas(){
        String[] columnas = new String[]{"_id", "fecha"};
        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("Personas", columnas, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

`MainActivity`

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private DatabaseHandler baseDatos;
        private ImagenAdapter cursorAdapter;
        private ListView listViewPersonas;
        private Button botonAgregarPersona;
        private int CODIGO_RESULT_EDITAR_PERSONA = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            listViewPersonas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPersonas);
            botonAgregarPersona = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonAgregarPersona);

            botonAgregarPersona.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    editarPersona(0);
                }
            });

           // Se recuperan todas las personas de la base de datos.
        recuperarTodasPersonas();

        // Asocio los menús contextuales al listViewPersonas.
        registerForContextMenu(listViewPersonas);
        }

     * Metodo publico que se sobreescribe. En este metodo creo el menu contextual
     * para el ListView de personas.

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.opciones_personas, menu);
        }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que se sobreescribe. En este metodo coloco las acciones de las opciones del menu contextual
     * para el ListView de personas. 
     */

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_contextual_editar_persona:
                    editarPersona((int)info.id);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onContextItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart(){
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume(){
            super.onResume();;
        }

     * Metodo privado que recupera todos las personas existentes de la base de datos.

        private void recuperarTodasPersonas() {
            try{
                baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(this);
                Cursor cursor = baseDatos.obtenerTodasPersonas();

                String[] from = new String[]{
                        "fecha"
                };

                int[] to = new int[]{
                        R.id.textViewFecha,
                };
                cursorAdapter = new ImagenAdapter(this, cursor, from, to);
                listViewPersonas.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
            }finally{
                baseDatos.cerrar();
            }
        }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que edita una persona.
     * @param p_id
     */

        public void editarPersona(int p_id){
            if(p_id == 0){
                Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditarPersonaActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(actividad_editarPersona, CODIGO_RESULT_EDITAR_PERSONA);
            }else{
                Persona persona;
                try{
                    persona = baseDatos.getPersona(p_id);
                    Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(this, EditarPersonaActivity.class);
                    actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("id", p_id);
                    actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("fecha", persona.getFecha());
                    startActivityForResult(actividad_editarPersona, CODIGO_RESULT_EDITAR_PERSONA);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    baseDatos.cerrar();
                }
            }
        }

* El metodo protegido se sobreescribe. Se llama con el resultado de otra actividad
     * requestCode es el codigo original que se manda a la actividad
     * resultCode es el codigo de retorno, 0 significa que todo salió bien
     * intent es usado para obtener alguna información del caller.

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            recuperarTodasPersonas();
        }
    }
```

**EDITO1:** Más información.

`MainActivity`, aquí es dónde tengo mi `ListView` (donde se cargan los datos de la `Sqlite`) y un botón `botonAgregarPersona` cuando hago clic en el, me lleva a mi `editarPersonaActivity` ahí creo una nueva persona rellenando el `EditTextFecha` con mi `DatePickerDialog` y `TimePickerDialog` hago clic en mi botón `butonGuardar` que guarda los datos en la `Sqlite` y me lleva a mi `MainActivity` aquí ya tengo mi nueva persona creada, en mi `ListView` pulsando encima de mi nueva persona me sale el menú, clic en editar y me lleva a `editarPersonaActivity` aquí puedo editar la persona que acabo de crear, pues lo que quiero aquí es que automáticamente en `EditTextFecha` me salga lo que le puse al crear la persona, para así decidir yo si quiero editar o no ese campo, ya que ahora mismo me sale vacío cuando lo quiero editar, obligándome a elegir de nuevo una fecha/hora

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si entiendo bien, ¿quieres que te muestre la fecha de nacimiento en el cuadro de texto una vez insertada la persona?

Comment: ¿Pasas a otra pantalla después de llamar este método: `baseDatos.actualizarRegistros`? ¿Pulsas en un botón Editar?

Comment: Entonces la fecha desaparece cuando pasas a esa otra pantalla?

Comment: Claro, el proceso es el siguiente empiezo en `MainActivity`, hago clic el botón crear persona, me lleva a la activity `editarPersonaActivity` (que es donde la creo) añado una fecha y hora en `editTextFecha` mediante `DatePickerDialog` y `TimePickerDialog` hago clic en el botón guardar, guarda los datos en `Sqlite` y me lleva a `MainActivity` donde se ve reflejada la persona que acabo de crear, pues pulso encima de esa persona, me sale mi menú, clic en editar (que llama al método `editarPersona` ) y aquí no me sale la fecha que introduje al crear la persona @A.Cedano

Comment: El problema está en MainActivity posiblemente, ¿podrías poner esa clase en la pregunta?

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que has explicado, en tu MainActivity deberías asignar al textView que no te muestra nada la fecha de la persona. Pero eso no lo haces (al menos no lo veo en el código de MainActivity). Supongo que ese textView está en el layout `activity_main.xml` ...

Comment: `textView` si me muestra la fecha, es `editTextFecha` el que no me la muestra al **editar** la persona, la fecha que añadi al **crearla** ... Se ve en el *GIF* @A.Cedano

Comment: Espera, edito mi respuesta. No cambies nada.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta editada. Debes setear la fecha al `editTextFecha`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT DEFINITIVO:**

Si al intentar setear la fecha desde el método `editarPersona()` no te funciona significa que algo falla en la lógica de tu aplicación. Es mejor revisar el orden lógico de la misma.

**EDIT**

No estás seteando la fecha al EditText en el método `editarPersona()` **atención, dentro del bloque `try {`**

En el método

```
        public void editarPersona(int p_id){
//    ... código que ya hay

               try{
                    persona = baseDatos.getPersona(p_id);
//agregar esto
                    editTextFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFecha);
                    editTextFecha.setText(persona.getFecha());
//... resto del código
```

Comment: _hago clic en mi botón butonGuardar que guarda los datos en la Sqlite y me lleva a mi MainActivity aquí ya tengo mi nueva persona creada, en mi ListView pulsando encima de mi nueva persona me sale el menú, clic en editar y me lleva a editarPersonaActivity aquí puedo editar la persona que acabo de crear_ Todo eso lo puedes hacer mostrando los datos de la persona que acabas de crear en la misma vista en que la has creado. ¿Por qué cambiar de Activity, mostrar de nuevo la persona en una lista, pulsar en editar ... ? son pasos innecesarios.

Comment: Estás mezclando dos cosas: Una cosa es un listview donde ves a todos tus usuarios y seleccionas a uno para editarlo. Otra es que, al acabar de crear una persona tengas que pasar por el listview para seleccionarla de nuevo y editarla. En este caso NO necesitas mostrar la lista. Lo lógico es que cargues AHÍ mismo los datos que acabas de crear y los edites. El listview te servirá para cuando quieras elegir entre las personas, pero en el caso 2 ya tienes la persona elegida, que es la que se acaba de crear. ¿No ves el error en tu lógica?

Comment: Edita la pregunta poniendo las clases MainActivity y EditarPersona como las tienes ahora. Las revisaré y trataré de seguir esa lógica de ir y venir de un lado para otro para encontrar una salida. Y también dime si el listview muestra la fecha que quieres editar.

Comment: A ver si te entiendo: Una vez **creada** la persona pulsas en el **botón editar**, que te lleva al MainActivity donde tienes tu listview. En el listview ves las personas de la BD, incluida la que acabas de crear, la seleccionas y quieres que en el editText te muestre su fecha de nacimiento, pero el editText lo tienes en la clase EditarPersona... ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Lo solucione! Me faltaba:  if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
            editTextFecha.setText(extras.getString("fecha"));
para que actualizase mi `editTextFecha` al abrir la clase para editar la persona, muchas gracias por tu ayuda @A.Cedano

Comment: Me alegro. De todos modos, perdona que sea pesado, pero cuando tiempo revisa la lógica de la app. Java tiene funciones que nos facilitan mucho las cosas, como ya te dije en otros comentarios. Y también cuando seleccionamos en una lista, se puede después de la selección iniciar una acción sin tener que abrir una ventana y pulsar en un botón Editar u otro. Saludos.

Comment: Para nada eres pesado, estoy empezando y me has ayudado mucho, gracias a tu comentario he cambiado la lógica de mi aplicación y estoy poniendo el código más simple y fácil y ahora estoy teniendo que hacer menos cambios de los que pensaba, por favor añade esto a tu respuesta y te la marco como solución, gracias @A.Cedano !